# When should I bid on an obscure domain name that is up for auction?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

A variant of my domain name is up for auction by the registrar, who caught the name after a cybersquatter allowed it to expire (as is this very "popular" registrar's policy for expiring domain names).

The opening bid is very low, and I'd like to *quietly* pick it up without attracting the attention of "investors" - i.e., squatters who might try to bid on it so that they can turn around and try to sell it to me for much more. (joke's on them, I really don't care enough to pay more than the opening bid - it would be a lose-lose for both of us!)

This registrar's auction platform displays all current bids, as well as the number of views (I have been avoiding clicking on the actual item page, so as not to increase the view count). If I bid on it now, with X days remaining, is this likely to attract squatters to bid on it?

My reasoning is that a squatter could come across the listing on the auction directory, see that it is a variant of an actual in-use domain name of a real entity, and then connect this to the fact that someone has bid on it, to try and turn a quick profit.

Strategically is it better to wait then, until the auction has nearly ended? If so, how long should I wait? 30 minutes? 10 minutes? 10 seconds? Or should I just let the auction expire completely and then buy it?

Comment: Your concern is valid - in my experience, the more views and bids there are on a domain, the more bidding will take place. I suspect that _some_ registrars and domain holding sites actually bid against bidders to drive up the price. I'd figure out the exact time the auction is going to end and place your bid then. Many sites offer automatic bidding with a maximum bid amount, so I'd suggest picking another domain that's up for auction and experimenting on that so you can quickly do the same for the domain you're interested in. You might want to give yourself a few minutes leeway too.

Comment: If there aren't many views on the domain, and it doesn't have a lot of backlinks to it, you could wait for it to expire and use a domain back order service. It might take some time for the domain to actually expire though (up to 90 days in some cases), and there's no guarantee that the registrant or registrar won't just register it again despite the lack of bids and views too... so bidding now as close to possible, with a maximum amount set, is likely your best/most timely opportunity to register it. That will also maintain the original creation date too, since it's considered a transfer.